# How to trim a video with regarding size/time in android?

Tags: android, video, video-streaming

I would like to create application like https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=in.shrthnd.cinedroid

what i tried is,

https://github.com/uday-rayala/video-trimmer through this url i have done video trimming with regarding to time limit.It just upload videos in sdcard and can trim it as much as we want.

what i need is,

While i am regarding the video,i can able to trim video with certain time limit.

Can i change bitrate and frame rate of a video recorder?